# Parse push notifications not being delivered iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push

I have not ever been able to send a push notification and have it be successfully delivered. All devices are registering for push notifications and all seems well but they never get my notification.
The app name, ID, and certificates are all correct.

Comment: Are pushing from production or sandbox? How are you signing the app?

Comment: @C.B. I am pushing from production. Signing the app as a Distribution